# Need help downloading a file using java in my app, it tries but quickly disappears

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download a zip file and save it to the sdcard.

I have a button with the id "download"

When I click the button, the dialog shows up and quickly disapears.

Here's what the code section looks like.

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public void download(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.download:
            startDownload();
    }
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "https://mydownloadurl";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mydownload.zip");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int)((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
```

And the only thing that shows in the logcat is

> 17586-17586/com.tyler.myapp D/qdmemalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x6da9b000 size:1892352 offset:0 fd:47
>   17586-17586/com.tyler.myapp D/qdmemalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:52
>   17586-17586/com.tyler.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
>   17586-17586/com.tyler.myapp D/qdmemalloc: ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x6da9b000 size:1892352
>   17586-17586/com.tyler.myapp D/qdmemalloc: ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002a000 size:4096
>   596-5470/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42942fe8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41dab9b0, pid=17586, inputType=0x(null)

Comment: Your code is probably throwing an exception in `doInBackground()`. In your `catch` block you should log the exception so you can see what the problem is. You can do so like this: `Log.e("Downloader - doInBackground()", "Error while downloading", e);`

Comment: Also, did you specify `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: If you format your code properly when you post it, we would have a much easier time looking at it and seeing potential issues

Comment: aha! Now since I have that in my catch block, it tells me I have no INTERNET permission. That is something I just need to add to the manifest right?

Comment: okay I added "uses permission" internet and write external storage to the manifest. That fixed it, thanks Daniel.. Im learning ok...

Comment: @DanielGabriel I think adding that as an answer would be worthwhile...might be helpful to others and a great suggestion. `Exceptions` should never be caught and not handled

Comment: I agree, that along with adding the permissions was the answer I needed.

Comment: Posted as an answer! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably throwing an exception in `doInBackground()`. In your catch block you should log the exception so you can see what the problem is. You can do so like this:

`Log.e("Downloader - doInBackground()", "Error while downloading", e);`

Also, did you specify `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: If I could upvote I would. Also I needed the permission INTERNET just a heads up to others who may come here.

Comment: Okay now if the file I am downloading is large (100mb) andro async stops here: 2668-2668/com.tyler.myapp D/ANDRO_ASYNC: -3566600       Any way to make it finish the download?

Comment: To figure out this problem you need to add more logging. Log the length of the file, the number of bytes read on each iteration. Also check that your `Integer.parseInt` in `onPostExecute()` doesn't throw an exception.